# How to create a locale with i18n based on a String value of language

Tags: ruby, rails-i18n

How is it possible to init/create a locale, based on a language String value `FR`, for example ? I tried it as follows in `irb` and it failed:

```
I18n.locale = :fr
I18n::InvalidLocale: :fr is not a valid locale
...
I18n.locale = 'FR'
I18n::InvalidLocale: :fr is not a valid locale
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/commit/4a3c6da3584530226d23bc2c33dc0226096f5c74) change enforce_available_locales value to false

```
# irb console
require 'i18n'
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false
I18n.locale = :fr
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The above snippet works. But, compared to Java, where we can create a Locale based on a language String passing it in to the constructor, is it possible to do the same with i18n gem ? - get Country name based on the language String value ?

Comment: I think, the only solution would be to use a third-party gem like `countries` for example: https://github.com/hexorx/countries

Comment: I18n is for handling translations. If you are looking for country object constructor, go ahead with `countries` gem.